# How can I keep alive my FTP connection (over curlftpfs)?

Tags: 12.10, ftp

I have curlftpfs on my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop, but my wifi router is bad and drops FTP connections after 30 seconds of inactivity. Is there a keep-alive setting with curlftpfs or if not are there any other options? I have tried the built in connect to server gui, but your server disappears after reboot. SSHFS is no good either, I need to mount to a particular directory (the server is my web host), otherwise it's a pain to find my content. Google hasn't yielded any answers either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bash script that does a loop and sleeps for 10 seconds, after that it should run `touch /mnt/ftp/tmp` and then `rm /mnt/ftp/tmp`.

#!/bin/bash
while [ "true" ]
do
  touch /mnt/ftp/tmp
  rm /mnt/ftp/tmp
  sleep 10
done